# OWL API to check existence of a class in an ontology

Tags: owl, owl-api

How can we check if a class exists in an ontology using the OWL API?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like once you've opened your ontology as an `OWLOntology`, you would use the method [`containsClassInSigature`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology.html#containsClassInSignature(org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI)) which takes an IRI and returns true if the ontology contains a class identified by that IRI:

> ### containsClassInSignature
>
> `boolean containsClassInSignature(IRI owlClassIRI)`
>
> Determines if the signature of this ontology contains an OWLClass with the specified IRI.
>
> **Parameters:**
> `owlClassIRI` - The IRI of the OWLClass to check for.
>
> **Returns:**
> `true` if the signature of this ontology contains an OWLClass that has `owlClassIRI` as its IRI, otherwise `false`.